# Linking to PDFs via attribute field of shapefile for ArcGIS Online?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, arcgis-online, pdf, hyperlink

I am working with some data that cannot be presented in an attribute table.  Therefore I would like to attach a specific PDF to each point within a shapefile.

Is there a way this can be done in ArcGIS for Desktop and then uploaded to ArcGIS Online so that an interactive map can be published with this information?

Comment: What you are describing is hyperlinks so perhaps try searching on that.

Comment: See ... [Using Hyperlinks](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s500000004000000)

Comment: I'd say this is more about attachments, not hyperlinks.

Comment: Then try ... [Enabling Attachments](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//01m90000000r000000)

Comment: @ian Shapefiles do not support attachments.

Comment: @PolyGeo right, I missed the shapefile part. I suppose the answer is no then unless the PDFs are also hosted online somewhere for the hyperlinking to work. Otherwise, I just tested uploading a file geodatabase with attachments to AGOL, and everything came over fine. I believe you do need a paid AGOL account though.

Comment: @ian I would have hoped that ArcGIS Online would support web accessible PDF file locations as hyperlinks, but when I last investigated this a couple of years ago I had to use a file geodatabase and attachments too.  If there is not an existing ArcGIS Idea for ArcGIS Online to support hyperlinks on shapefiles then I think it would be very useful for someone (perhaps the asker here) to submit.

Answer (score 2):

I've just tested this using a point feature class in a file GDB.  The point feature class contains two attributes (Name and Hyperlink).  The Hyperlink field is just a Text(200) so should be compatible with shapefile limitations.
[image]

Published this up as a feature service in ArcGIS Online, open in a Map Viewer, click on the feature then click on the **More info** tag.  The hyperlinked PDF opened in a new browser tab (Chrome) with no issues.  I did not do any configuration in the Map Viewer...this appears to be default behaviour.

[image]
[image]
[image]

I did not test publishing a shapefile to ArcGIS Online...I only ever use shapefiles as a export file format and **never** use them for processing or data storage, the format has too many limitations.  It's a simple matter to import the shapefile to a staging file gdb and publish from there.

Answer (score 0):

I would have hoped that ArcGIS Online would support web accessible PDF file locations as hyperlinks, but when I last investigated this a couple of years ago I had to use a file geodatabase and attachments too. If there is not an existing ArcGIS Idea for ArcGIS Online to support hyperlinks on shapefiles then I think it would be very useful for someone (perhaps the asker here) to submit.

Answer (score -2):

You can link to a file on a local drive or server by adding the prefix "file://" before the path
ex:
file://C:\users\joeb\desktop\test.txt

Comment: that is correct for files needed to be shared over the internet however, I specified that my answer was for local drives or servers.